# Getting the menu handle

Tags: winapi

I created menus and sub menus using the resource editor in visual studio. I now want to add items to one of the menus during run time. I was going to use the `InsertMenuItem` function but I don't know how to get access to the `HMENU` variable.

Comment: [GetMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`LoadMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) seems is what you need. Use it to load menu from resource editor, something like this:

```
HMENU yourMenu = LoadMenu( hInst,  // variable where you stored your HINSTANCE
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDM_MENU1) );  // replace IDM_MENU1 with the ID of your menu
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Extended_Menu_Template_Format) are lots of useful examples, you may find very useful. Some of them address your issue, and some might be useful to you in the future. I would study the `Example of Menu-Item Bitmaps` section if I were you...

If you need a menu handle that is already assigned to a window then use [GetMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as member *arx* said. Something like this:

```
HMENU yourMenu = GetMenu(hWnd);  // hWnd is the HWND of the window that owns your menu
```

Do not forget to destroy the menu when it is no longer needed ( usually upon window destruction ) with [DestroyMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647631%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

[This](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/menus.html) example might help you as well. This is very good introductory tutorial for Win32, I suggest you to read it ( just go to the home page and download **both** PDF and `.zip` file with code examples ).

As I have said before, your question is not entirely clear, so if you have further questions leave me a comment.

Hopefully this answer solved your problems. Best regards.